# Can we simulate Edgecore Datacenter switch on any virtual environment

Tags: networking, docker-datacenter

Datacenter has many hardware switches like edgecore switch. Just wanted to check if we can simulate them on a virtual environment for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Open vSwitch is a Software Switch which does all that hardware switch supports or maybe more. I read about it long back. Here is the link to the site:

http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/what-is-ovs/

I have not used it personally, might be of help to what you are looking for. Thanks